# Bind to the "value" of ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<object, string>>

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, observablecollection, keyvaluepair

I want to bind my combo box ItemsSourse to the "value" i.e. (string component) of the

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<object, string>>.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection and then set the [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to Value:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

The values in the combo box will then match the Values from the KeyValuePairs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go would be to use the `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Pairs}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

Alternatively, you could expose a new property in your viewmodel that will only contain the values. For example:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> AllValues { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    AllValues = new ObservableCollection<string>(Pairs.Select(x => x.Value));
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllValues}" />
```

Comment: Although the thought of using `ObservableCollection` for data binding is right, this is not a feasible solution: [the constructor that takes an `IEnumerable` as argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) _copies_ all values, effectively voiding the purpose of binding to the values of the original `KeyValuePair` collection.